# Python Pyro4 - Get client IP

Tags: python-3.x, pyro4

I want the server to get the caller's IP in any way. E.g. client calls function on server that checks his IP.

Also I want to know how to get my own external IP using pure Python or built-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers are in the manual.

[Pyro4.current_context](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/tipstricks.html#client-information-on-the-current-context-correlation-id)

[Pyro4.socketutil.getIpAddress](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/api/util.html#Pyro4.socketutil.getIpAddress)